# Is die function accept only strings?

Tags: php, mysqli

this code works:

```
if (isset($db->error)) {
    echo $db->error;
}
```

This code in not working:

```
if (isset($db->error)) {
    die($db->error);
}
```

This is my DB class:

```
class Db {

    private $db,
            $error;


    public function __construct() {
        return $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, D_NAME);
        if ($this->db->connect_error) {
            $this->error = $this->db->connect_error;
        }
    }

}
```

"D_NAME" is wrong so an error appears but I didn't kill the page, content still appear after the error. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` block in the constructor is never executed, because you are returning `$this->db`:

```
public function __construct() {
        return $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, D_NAME);
        // the lines after return will never be executed!
}
```

This is the first reason why the `$db->error` is unset.

The second reason is that the `$error` member is `private`, which means that you are not allowed to access this property directly. So you should make it accessible in one of the following ways *(at least)*:

- make it public;
- implement the [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [`__isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) magic methods;
- implement a getter method.

**Using public `$error`**

```
class Db {
  private $db;
  public $error;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'sss3', 'a4J1uQzQCasD', 's3_small');
    if ($this->db->connect_error) {
      $this->error = $this->db->connect_error;
    }
    return $this->db;
  }

}

$db = new Db;
if (isset($db->error)) {
  die($db->error);
}

echo 'xxx', PHP_EOL;
```

**Using `__isset` and `__get` magic methods**

```
class Db {
  private $db;
  private $error;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'sss3', 'a4J1uQzQCasD', 's3_small');
    if ($this->db->connect_error) {
      $this->error = $this->db->connect_error;
    }
    return $this->db;
  }

  public function __get($key) {
    if ($key === 'error') {
      return $this->error;
    }
  }

  public function __isset($key) {
    if ($key === 'error') {
      return isset($this->error);
    }
  }

}

$db = new Db;
if (isset($db->error)) {
  die($db->error);
}

echo 'xxx', PHP_EOL;
```

**Implementing a getter method**

A getter method is just a method returning value of a private member. In our case it is `$error`. So you might leave it private, but add a method to access its value. For instance:

```
public function getError() {
  return $this->error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot to understand. Much appreciated :)

Comment: why would you mentioned magic methods and you didn't getters/setters?

Comment: @Robert, well, I might as well mention the pattern designs. But I've just added info about getters =) Ah, no need in setters here. I doubt he expects the user to set his error into a DBAL. Thanks.

Comment: using getter is still better than using magic method or public property

Comment: @Robert, the matter of preference